# Dynamically appending a row by cloning an existing row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row in a table and that row is not displayed as css style is set to `display:none` .

### HTML table:

```
<table class="myTable">
    <tr class="prototype">
    ........
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS code:

```
.myTable .prototype{display:none;}
```

Now i have to clone the same row and add some data to it and append the row to the table as below: i have below jquery code:

```
var master = $(this).parents("table.myTable");

var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
prot.attr("class", "");
prot.find("#attributeValue").attr("value", "ABC");
prot.find("#contactFirstName").attr("value", "XYZ");

jQuery('table.myTable tr:last').before(prot);
```

But the row won'ttbe added to the table. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this code part of an event handler? You're referencing `this` but there's no context for it in the question

Comment: yes.it is called on page load..

Comment: If that's the case then `this` would be the `document`, which has no parent(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var master = $(this).parents("table.myTable");

var prot = master.find("tr.prototype").clone();
prot.removeClass('prototype');
prot.find("#attributeValue").val("ABC");
prot.find("#contactFirstName").val("XYZ");

master.append(prot);
prot.show();
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Also in my code var master = $(this).parents("table.myTable"); this line is wrong. First i need to get the table. because this logic is called on page load. not on any button click. How can i change the first line?

Comment: `var master = $("table.myTable"); `

Comment: Ok. I thought this code was called in an event handler. Best option is to give the table an "Id". Then you can select it from anywhere by `$('#TableId')`.

Comment: your code still has mistakes (selector in the first row, possible multiple ids)

Comment: @abhi, one more small help. prot has a check box with id myCheck. How can i check the check box programmatically?  prot.find("#myCheck").prop('checked', true); is not working

Comment: @Raidri It was unknown at the time of answer whether the code was being called from inside an event handler or not. If it were, then it would have been correct. Because, it is mentioned in the comments, the correction should be made as an addendum at the end of the answer. Moreover, `$("table.myTable")` will also select multiple elements if that class is applied to many elements. But, yes, thank you indeed for trying to help.

Comment: @user1016403 Once you have added the row to the table and your code goes out of scope, you cannot use the variable `prot`. If it is an "ID" (which is supposed to be unique), then you can simply: `$('#myCheck').prop("checked", true);`

Comment: @Abhi, cannot i write this line $('#myCheck').prop("checked", true); before adding the row to table? Thanks!

Comment: In that case your earlier code was fine. Just do an attribute. prot.find("#myCheck").attr('checked', 'checked');

Answer (score 1):

1. If you run the code in the onLoad event, change the first line to `var master = $(this).find("table.myTable");` or `var master = $("table.myTable");`
2. Use `prot.removeClass();` instead of `prot.attr("class", "");`
3. Ids have to be unique, if elements in your prototype-row have an id you get invalid HTML.
4. Use `$().val('ABC')` instead of `$().attr('value', 'ABC')`

If it still doesn't work, please show more code (maybe a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)).